# jquery selectors not working?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am creating result card of some students, students are in dropdowns and when I want to select any student, the other dropdowns auto select data of that student.

Another point when I click add row, It should copy the whole row and then I will choose another student and the results should show.

Here is my code and I stuck. Need some help what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function){
          var cloned=$("tagihan").html();


         $(document).on("click", "tambah", function() {
         console.log(cloned);
         //$('#aaa').append(cloned);
         $("#tagihan").appned(cloned)


         });
         var unit;
         var toMove;
         $(document).on("change". "unit", function(e){

         //unit = $(this).closest('tr.detail_tagihan').("#unit").text();
            unit=$(this).closest("tr").find(".unit").val();

         $(this).closest("tr").find(".option-container").children().appendTo(".layanan");

         toMove= $(this).closest("tr").find(".layanan"). children("[data-unit!='"+unit+"']");
         toMove.appendTo(".option-container");
         $(this).closest("tr").find(".layanan").removeAttr("disabled");


         });

         });

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="aaa"></div>
      <table name="tagihan" class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th><b>Math</b></th>
               <th><b>Computer</b></th>
               <th><b>Physics</b></th>
               <th><b>English</b></th>
               <th colspan="2">
                  <b>
                     <Total marks>
                  </b>
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tagihan">
            <tr id="Total Marks" class="obtain marks">
               <td>
                  <select>
                     <option value="Asad">Asad</option>
                     <option value="Adil">Adil</option>
                     <option value="AAmir">AAmir</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <select>
                  <td>
                     <option value="Science">Science</option>
                     < option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                     <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                     <option value="English">English</option>
                     <
               <select id="layanan" class=" layanan selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" disabled>
               <option data-unit="Asad" value="23">23</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="25">25</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="33">33</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="34">34</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="44">44</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="45">45</option>
               </select>
               <span id="option-container" class = "option-container" style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute;"></span>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" id="Keterangan" class=" Keterangan form-control" placeholder="Keterangan">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" id="Harga" class="Harga form-control" placeholder="Harga">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tambah" >Tambah</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the browser's error console? That `.on("change". "unit"` should throw a syntax error.

Comment: Here are some syntex/typo error in your code, like `$(document).on("change". "unit", function(e){` should be `$(document).on("change", ",unit", function(e){` and `$(document).on("click", "tambah", function() {` should be `$(document).on("click", "#tambah", function() {`

Comment: _“Need some help what is wrong.”_ - mainly that you completely failed to give us an actual problem description. No, just showing code and telling us that you are “stuck” isn’t one. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @CBroe9 I have provided complete file and it is giving errors, If you know about firebug. You can copy and run in any browser where you will see some errors.. ??? Are you developer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is wrong line:

```
 $(document).ready(function){
```

correct with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Here are problems and need to correct html:

```
 <select>
                  <td>
                     <option value="Science">Science</option>
                     < option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                     <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                     <option value="English">English</option>
                     <
               <select id="layanan" class=" layanan selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" disabled>
               <option data-unit="Asad" value="23">23</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="25">25</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="33">33</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="34">34</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="44">44</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="45">45</option>
               </select>
               <span id="option-container" class = "option-container" style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute;"></span>
               </td>
```

It should be:

```
<td>
               <select> 
                     <option value="Science">Science</option>
                     <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                     <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                     <option value="English">English</option>
                     </select>
               </td>
               <td>   
               <select id="layanan" class=" layanan selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" disabled>
               <option data-unit="Asad" value="23">23</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="25">25</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="33">33</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="34">34</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="44">44</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="45">45</option>
               </select>
               <span id="option-container" class = "option-container" style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute;"></span>
               </td>
```

**Here is complete solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
       $( document ).ready(function() {

            var cloned = $("#results").html();
            $(".subjects").trigger("click");

            $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {

                 console.log(cloned);
                 //$('#aaa').append(cloned);
                 $("tbody#results").append(  cloned );
             });

             var studentSelected;
             var subjectSelected;

               $(document).on("change", ".subjects", function() { 
                 studentSelected = $(this).closest("tr").find(".students").val();
                 subjectSelected = $(this).val();

                 $(this).closest("tr").find(".students").removeAttr("disabled");
                 $(this).closest("tr").find(".obtain_marks").val(studentSelected+"-"+subjectSelected);

                 if( parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find(".obtain_marks").text()) >= 50) {
                     $(this).closest("tr").find(".result").val('Passed');
                 }else {
                     $(this).closest("tr").find(".result").val('Failed');
                 }

                console.log(parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find(".obtain_marks").text()));

             });

              $(document).on("change", ".students", function() {  
                 subjectSelected = $(this).closest("tr").find(".subjects").val();
                 studentSelected = $(this).val();

                 $(this).closest("tr").find(".students").removeAttr("disabled");
                 $(this).closest("tr").find(".obtain_marks").val(studentSelected+"-"+subjectSelected);

                 if( parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find(".obtain_marks").text()) >= 50 ) {
                     $(this).closest("tr").find(".result").val('Passed');
                 }else {
                     $(this).closest("tr").find(".result").val('Failed');
                 }

             });

/**/
     });

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="aaa"></div>
      <table name="tagihan" class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th><b>Student Name</b></th>
               <th><b>Subject</b></th> 
               <th><b>Obtain Marks</b></th> 
               <th  >
                  <b>
                      Total Marks 
                  </b>
               </th>
               <th><b>Result</b></th>
               <th></th> 
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="results">
            <tr id="tagihanx">
               <td>
                  <select   class="students" >
                     <option value="Asad">Asad</option>
                     <option value="Adil">Adil</option>
                     <option value="AAmir">AAmir</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                     <select   class="subjects" > 
                        <option value="Science">Science</option>
                        <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                        <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                     </select>
               </td>
               <td>   
               <select   class=" obtain_marks form-control " data-live-search="true" disabled>
                   <option data-unit="Asad" value="Asad-Computer">53</option>
                   <option data-unit="Asad" value="Asad-Physics">43</option>
                   <option data-unit="Asad" value="Asad-English">33</option>
                   <option data-unit="Asad" value="Asad-Science">44</option>

               <option data-unit="Adil" value="Adil-Computer">43</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="Adil-Physics">63</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="Adil-English">73</option>
               <option data-unit="Adil" value="Adil-Science">44</option>

               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="AAmir-Computer">66</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="AAmir-Physics">44</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="AAmir-English">77</option>
               <option data-unit="AAmir" value="AAmir-Science">45</option>

               </select>
                </td>
               <td>
                  <span   class=" total_marks Keterangan form-control" placeholder="Keterangan"> 100 </span>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text"  class="Harga form-control result" placeholder="result">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add" >add</button>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
</html>
```